# Cannot find tensorflow (or some other python package) during screen?

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow

My code works very well without screen command.
But once I screen, it shows cannot find TensorFlow, I just curious how it possible?
I use the same python environment with and without screen.

Is it the screen command reset some global variables?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! screen command will unset some global variables

you can set global variables when use screen as follows:

```
screen env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH bash
```